# Why is Integer.MAX_VALUE+1 smaller than Integer.MAX_VALUE?

Tags: java

I am simply trying to add numbers from 1 to Integer.MAX_VALUE, but in output I'm getting nothing. The program is struck in between. Below is the class that I created.

```
 public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long sum = 0;
        int start_value = 1;
        long end_value = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        while(start_value <= end_value){
            sum += start_value;
            start_value++;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
 }
```

Do anybody have any idea why this is hanging. This program is never completed.

How to solve this type of problem?

Comment: You can fix this by replacing `int start_value = 1;` to `long start_value = 1;`.

Comment: Thanks a lot got the answer.

Answer (score 3):

It should never complete as you have an infinite loop.

Your loop is effectively

```
while(start_value <= Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
```

but the Integer.MAX_VALUE is the largest by definition so it is effective

```
while (true) {
```

You can change the loop to do what you need

```
int start_value = 0;
while(start_value < end_value) {
    start_value++;
    sum += startValue;
}
```

This way you can catch the problem before it fails.

An obtuse solution might be

```
for (int i = 1; i > 0; i++)
    sum += i;
```

This would stop when `i` overflows.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of something called integer Overflow. When you add `1` to the `MAX_VALUE`, you get `MIN_VALUE` if you are using signed integers, or `0` if using unsigned integers.

Briefly explained, when you add `1` to `99` for example, you have to carry the `1` twice to end up on the third digit: `100`. But if you only had a maximum of 2 digits allowed, then you carry the one twice, and end up with `00`. In computers, there is a limited numbers of bits (binary digits) allowed, usually 32 or 64.

You can read more about it here:
[Wiki Integer Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)
[Signed vs Unsigned Integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signedness)

Comment: Thanks...
Got the answer

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers where you're stuck in an infinite loop because the the max integer value is never reached, you should maybe add a print inside the loop so you can see progress:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    long sum = 0;
    int start_value = 1;
    int end_value = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1;//Just in case
    while(start_value <= end_value){
        sum += start_value;
        start_value++;

        //Print every 100 loops, change this if it prints too often
        if (start_value % 100 == 0){
           System.out.println("integer at: " + start_value + ", sum: " + sum);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum + Integer.MAX_VALUE);//Since we only went to Integer.MAX_VALUE -1

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the reasons indicated in the other answers, it can be quite tricky to iterate over intervals bounded by maximum or minimum values for a primitive type.

Java 8 allows a new solution to this, because `IntStream.rangeClosed` and `LongStream.rangeClosed` can be used.

In your case, you can do

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, Integer.MAX_VALUE).mapToLong(i -> i).sum();
```

or just

```
LongStream.rangeClosed(1, Integer.MAX_VALUE).sum();
```